# SSRS - Not displaying all the result rows in Preview Mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have created a report using Matrix and I have set the property "Keep together on One Page if Possible" to show the report in one page.But for some reason the reprot is not showing all the result rows,I see half hidden row.See screeshot
[image]

[image: Matrix report]

Comment: can you include the whole picture of your output that shows half hidden rows? its just half in your image. better check also the height and width of your table because it might be greater than your page width. and always remember to include the page margin on checking.

Comment: Yes its half hidden and that is exactly what I am trying to resolve and need help.

Comment: can you include that image of that half hidden?

Comment: i cannot include more then that as it gets hidden, dont understand what you mean

Comment: when you click Preview.. what is the output look like?

Comment: please see the updated screesnhot

Comment: i see that's a bit weird.

Comment: how output in preview when you zoom out less than 100%

Comment: try also to click Print Layout this might be not just one page.